# Singularity container - Binding a folder in a seperate partition

Tags: singularity-container

I have a private group project folder (let's call it `data_dir`) on a high performance cluster where I don't have root privileges. The folder is in a seperate partition.
I have a singularity container where I need to access `data_dir`. Official [documentation says](https://sylabs.io/guides/3.2/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html) `-B` flag is to bind path, but I can't access the folder within the container using `-B`. This is what I tried so far:

```sh
XXXXXX  login1[~/work/subcam] master ⦿ ➜  readlink data
/gpfs/projects/oceanvideo/data
XXXXXX  login1[~/work/subcam] master ⦿ ➜  singularity run -B $(readlink data):$(pwd)/data container.sif
WARNING: skipping mount of /local_scratch: no such file or directory

________                               _______________
___  __/__________________________________  ____/__  /________      __
__  /  _  _ \_  __ \_  ___/  __ \_  ___/_  /_   __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
_  /   /  __/  / / /(__  )/ /_/ /  /   _  __/   _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
/_/    \___//_/ /_//____/ \____//_/    /_/      /_/  \____/____/|__/


You are running this container as user with ID 21530 and group 21500,
which should map to the ID and group for your user on the Docker host. Great!

tf-docker ~/work/subcam > cd data
bash: cd: data: No such file or directory
tf-docker ~/work/subcam > cd /gpfs/
tf-docker /gpfs > ls
work
tf-docker /gpfs > cd projects
bash: cd: projects: No such file or directory
```

How can I access `data_dir` with the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-B` is the correct way to mount directories in the container. A few options:

1. If `/gpfs/projects/oceanvideo/data` is itself a symlink, it will not resolve inside the container and give that error code. `readlink` will only resolve a single level. Find the original, non-linked path and use that with `-B`.
2. If that is not the case, run with `singularity -vv run ...` to see if there is more information on why the directory is not being mounted.
3. Make sure that [the cluster allows user binds](https://singularity-admindoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/the_singularity_config_file.html#user-bind-control-boolean-default-yes)

Comment: `/gpfs/projects/oceanvideo/data` is the original path. I was not able to bind that folder to a local folder, e.g.: `data`, but I got it working with `-B $(readlink data):$(readlink data)`, binding the path to itself on container, and I was able to use the symlink as well.

Comment: Ok actually, just tried now and `-v` flag helped with binding locally as well. This was the error: `container creation failed: unable to add /gpfs/projects/oceanvideo/data to mount list: destination must be an absolute path`. So the local `data` is not an absolute path and when instead I used `$(realpath data)`, it worked. Also I could do this with other local paths like `data_dir`; I think it's overwriting the destination folder inside the container because `data` is normally already a symlink, not a folder